# Guide me to Best Solution for a time loop in Bashscript?

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I got my computer today to do work on a bashscript called `MF.sh`..

```
wget somefile1
wget somefile2
wget somefile3
```

Ok. But *somefiles familly* like to *change* every minute, so I wrote this amazing piece of code to repeat the work every minute:

```
sleep 45
./MF.sh
```

I ended up killing **zilllion** process in htop manually.

What is the best practice here? What type of loop to use? Where to break? Using "i" like control variable is just a convention? How to use minutes time to control this?

**EDIT** (expanding question instead of answering it)

I tryed this

```
h=$(date +%R) 
for ($(date +%R) = $h)

     then
```

to catch when minute changes, but failed.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your edit, but if you trying to accomplish something like repetition of a task every minute you could look into [watch](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_watch.htm)

Comment: Thanks @another.anon.coward I want to learn a little more about writing bashscripts programs. But, anyway, this is a very good tip, thank you. Didn't knew about 'watch' existence.. Learning all time. =D

Comment: Damn, can I see a equal sign in a bashscript expression? Ug, kill that guy! =D Go google @H_7

Comment: @another.anon.coward I mean, thank you very much man, in a funny way. =P

Comment: and I am advising myself to google more, and ask less too. (If you smile now, upvote this comment =D )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`while` loops while its command is true. `true` is always true.

```
while true
do ...
   ...
  if ...
  then
    break
  fi
   ...
done
```

Comment: I like this. True is always true. Sounds true.

Comment: Edited question, please take a quick look.

Comment: Done. I used a while loop with a `if [ $(date +%S) -eq 45 ]  # every minute, on 45 secs
 then` and that starts the job sequence every time seconds hit 45, what it means, every minute, since the sequence job is fast enough to execute in less than a minute, and slow enough to not execute in less than a second. Thank you again.

Answer (score 3):

For repeated tasks, you could use a [`cron`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/cron/) job.

Set up an entry in your [`crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) that looks like this:

```
1 * * * *       /path/to/MF.sh
```

This will execute `MF.sh` every minute (`*` instead of `1` also will do). If you change `1` to `3`, for example, it will be run every three minutes.

Not a loop solution, but in my opinion, this is what you need.

The man pages for [`cron`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/8/cron/) and [`crontab`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) will give you further instructions if you need any.

Comment: Nice idea @eckes, but I dont need this ALL time running, so I need a loop (and I want to learn about it to further use too) inside the script.

Comment: hmmm I guess cron can obvius configure for work some functions in just a period of time... Upvoting. =)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `timeout` function in coreutils.  It's brilliant.

Quick check, I used:

```
timeout 10s cat
```

After 10 seconds it kills the `cat` command and gave me a return code of `124`.

http://swik.net/Unix/BASH+Cures+Cancer+Blog/timeout+%E2%80%93+new+coreutils+command/e2fml

Answer (score 0):

The sintax for the if statement ask for bracklets like this from my "final" code working:

```
if [ $(date +%S) -eq 45 ]   # every minute, on 45 secs
    then
    ./GetFiles.sh       # starts files downloads script
    break
fi
```

You use `if` if you are using the While solution. I don't know yet the `for` solution for this. I will edit this answer when I get it.

Well the crime of calling the script from it is not so bad... if you know what you are doing (not my case, lol).  It's called Recursion > http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/recursionsct.html

Comment: ahhh, starting to learn python... nooo!... Dont know c++ yet! ug!